# Wait for multiple events in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, synchronization, grand-central-dispatch

What is equivalent of Win32's WaitForMultipleObjects function in iOS?

This is roughly what I want:

```
NSCondition *condition1;
NSCondition *condition2;
NSCondition *condition3;

wait_for_conditions([NSArray arrayWithObjects: condition1, condition2, condition3, nil], 
^{
    // Some code which must be executed when all conditions were fired
});

// in some other places of program:
[condition1 signal];

// ...
[condition2 signal];

// ...
[condition3 signal];
```

What are the ways to accomplish this in iOS?

Edit: I'm not bound to usage of NSCondition, any other synchronization things will be ok (I've just googled and found NSCondition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I ended up using my own solution using GCD's groups of blocks notifications. I've also used serial queue (instead of concurrent) which guarantees we create only 1 additional thread.

```
@interface WaitCondition : NSObject
    - (void) fire;
@end

@implementation WaitCondition {
    BOOL fired;
    NSCondition *condition;
}

- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        condition = [NSCondition new];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) fire
{
    [condition lock];
    [condition signal];
    fired = YES;
    [condition unlock];
}

- (void) wait
{
    [condition lock];
    while (!fired) {
        [condition wait];
    }
    [condition unlock];
}

@end

void Dispatch_NotifyForConditions(NSArray *conditions, dispatch_block_t completion)
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("notify_queue", NULL);
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    for (WaitCondition *condition in conditions)
    {
        NSCAssert([condition isKindOfClass:[WaitCondition class]], @"Dispatch_NotifyForConditions: conditions must contain WaitCondition objects only.");
        dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
            [condition wait];
        });
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, completion);

    dispatch_release(queue);
    dispatch_release(group);
}
```

Comment: I am confused, why is the fired variable needed? With most frameworks, you simply have one thread that does the work and calls signal and then another thread that calls wait and once signal is called, any waiters then proceed...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a NSNotifications for each condition with unique notification name.
Then for each notification will call the same function.

Comment: You could easily just have the function that's being called just be a checker to see if all conditions are satisfied yet before calling your main function

Comment: @Dancreek 'easily'? I think not. Check my answer for the 'easy' version. Hah.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
void async(void (^block)())
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(invoke) toTarget:[block copy] withObject:nil];
}

__attribute__((sentinel(NULL)))
void wait_for_conditions(void (^block)(), NSCondition *condition, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, condition);

    NSMutableArray *conditions = [NSMutableArray array];

    do {
        [conditions addObject:condition];
    } while ((condition = va_arg(args, NSCondition *)));

    va_end(args);

    NSCondition *overallCondition = [NSCondition new];

    for (int i = 0; i < conditions.count; i++) {
        NSCondition *cond = [conditions objectAtIndex:i];

        async(^{
            [cond lock];
            [cond wait];
            [cond unlock];

            [overallCondition lock];
            [overallCondition signal];
            [overallCondition unlock];
        });
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < conditions.count; i++) {
        [overallCondition lock];
        [overallCondition wait];
        [overallCondition unlock];
    }

    if (block)
        block();
}
```

Obviously this has the drawback of effectively doubling your threads, but I don't know if there is an easier way of accomplishing this.